# Could you explain the fun requestByZipCode?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a beginner of Kotlin.

The following code is from  Kotlin-for-Android-Developers at https://github.com/antoniolg/Kotlin-for-Android-Developers/tree/master-june-2017

Could you explain the fun **requestByZipCode** ? It's difficult to understand.

It seems that "**fun requestByZipCode(zipCode: Long, days: Int): ForecastList = requestToSources {**" is convenient code, I don't know whether a full code of the fun "**fun requestByZipCode(zipCode: Long, days: Int) ...**" is easy to understand.

```
class ForecastProvider(val sources: List<ForecastDataSource> = ForecastProvider.SOURCES) {

    companion object {
        val DAY_IN_MILLIS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
        val SOURCES by lazy { listOf(ForecastDb(), ForecastServer()) }
    }

    fun requestByZipCode(zipCode: Long, days: Int): ForecastList = requestToSources {
        val res = it.requestForecastByZipCode(zipCode, todayTimeSpan())
        if (res != null && res.size >= days) res else null
    }

    private fun <T : Any> requestToSources(f: (ForecastDataSource) -> T?): T = sources.firstResult { f(it) }

}



interface ForecastDataSource {
    fun requestForecastByZipCode(zipCode: Long, date: Long): ForecastList?
    fun requestDayForecast(id: Long): Forecast?
}



data class ForecastList(val id: Long, val city: String, val country: String, val dailyForecast: List<Forecast>) {
    val size: Int
        get() = dailyForecast.size
    operator fun get(position: Int) = dailyForecast[position]
}


interface ForecastDataSource {
    fun requestForecastByZipCode(zipCode: Long, date: Long): ForecastList?
    fun requestDayForecast(id: Long): Forecast?

}
```

Comment: If you give more specific questions, then we could give better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically doing:

```
fun requestByZipCode(zipCode: Long, days: Int): ForecastList {
    return sources.firstResult {
        val res = it.requestForecastByZipCode(zipCode, todayTimeSpan())
        if (res != null && res.size >= days) res else null
    }
}
```

And by looking at the repository, the `firstResult` extension function it would be:

```
fun requestByZipCode(zipCode: Long, days: Int): ForecastList {

        for (element in sources) {
            val res = element.requestForecastByZipCode(zipCode, todayTimeSpan())
            val result = if (res != null && res.size >= days) res else null
            if (result != null) return result
        }
        throw NoSuchElementException("No element matching predicate was found.")
 }
```

You might be having trouble understanding it because of the `Extension Function` on the List: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html